# How to insert JSON strings without ID property?

Tags: c#, sql-server, json

I have a class. I will insert converted JSON classes without the ID property.

While I insert that JSON string, an error occured because the ID was not inserted.

```
public class myClass
{
    public int ID{ get; set; }     
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string surname{ get; set; }

    public myClass(int Id, string Name, string Surname)
    {
        this.ID= Id;
        this.name= Name;
        this.surname=Surname;
    }
}
```

What I get now:

```
{
  "ID": "1",
  "name": "serial",
  "surname": "Fast"
}
```

What I want it to look like:

```
{
  "name": "Serial",
  "surname": "Fast"
}
```

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to serialize to JSON without ID?

Comment: you can use [JsonIgnore] property on the particular property..

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to ignore that class using ScriptIgnore.

```
using System;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class myClass
{
    // The JavaScriptSerializer ignores this field.
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public int ID{ get; set; }     

    // The JavaScriptSerializer serializes this field.
    public string name{ get; set; }
    public string surname{ get; set; }
}
```

[link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx)